# How do I access AJAX data within a controller method?

Tags: plugin-development, controller, ajax

I have a JavaScript file which sends an array of data to a controller:

```
Craft.postActionRequest('wineNotes/wineSpreadSheet/saveWines', data, ...)
```

The structure of the data variable is as follows:

```
var data = {
    Data: sData
}
```

... where `sData` is an array of temp variables `sData(temp1,temp2,...)` and the structure of each temp object is like this:

```
temp = {
    "wine":        ht.getDataAtCell(i,0),
    "country":     ht.getDataAtCell(i,1),
    "region":      ht.getDataAtCell(i,2),
    "note":        ht.getDataAtCell(i,3),
    "tastingdate": ht.getDataAtCell(i,4),
    "rating":      ht.getDataAtCell(i,5),
    "maturity":    ht.getDataAtCell(i,6),
    "conclusion":  ht.getDataAtCell(i,7)
};
```

How can I access the parameter `temp.wine` for each `temp` in the `sData` array within the following method of my controller?

```
public function actionSaveWines()
{
    // ???
}
```

I know the data structure is kinda wierd its actually an array of arrays. Read the below code and you might understand.

```
for(i=0;i<NumRows;i++)
        {
            temp = {
                "wine":ht.getDataAtCell(i,0),
                "country":ht.getDataAtCell(i,1),
                "region":ht.getDataAtCell(i,2),
                "tastingdate":ht.getDataAtCell(i,3),
                "rating":ht.getDataAtCell(i,4),
                "maturity":ht.getDataAtCell(i,5),
                "conclusion":ht.getDataAtCell(i,6),
            };
            sData.push(temp);
        }

        var data = {
            Data: sData,
        }
        Craft.postActionRequest('wineNotes/wineSpreadSheet/saveWines', data, function(response) {


        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Any properties of the object you pass into `Craft.postActionRequest()`’s second argument will be available to Craft as POST parameters, so you can get to them with [`HttpRequestService::getPost()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/httprequestservice#getPost):

```
$sData = craft()->request->getPost('Data');

foreach ($sData as $temp)
{
    $wine = $temp['wine'];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think you're close... I think their data structure is actually an **array** of `temp` objects (containing "wine", etc). So I think they'll need to loop through `$data`, and pull the value of `wine` out of each object in the array.

Comment: I have added the full code above maybe you can get a better idea why I dont think i can do $data = craft()->request->getPost('Data'); as i have many of these 'Data' varaibles inside another array

Comment: @user3309362 Thanks, just updated my answer.